# trying to put the screen data in a file and save it

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to get the printed data on the screen into a file loop runs continuous

here is an example of the screen data:

```
2022-03-15 00:45:02.589167+00:00
13.808354168465078
251.00362159176666
608.2925249357038
2022-03-15 00:46:02.592169+00:00
13.649351418095947
251.2013534045143
603.6849759739406
```

And here it the original code:

```py
from pysolar.solar import *
import datetime
import time

latitude = 47.4569019
longitude = -122.2095766

while True:
 
    date = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)

    print(date)

    print(get_altitude(latitude, longitude, date))
    print(get_azimuth(latitude, longitude, date))

    altitude_deg = get_altitude(latitude, longitude, date)
    print(radiation.get_radiation_direct(date, altitude_deg))

    time.sleep(60)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP is already solved his problem, but using Python `with open` is generally safer and the recommended way. Furthermore, OP piece of code require external exit prompt (such as `CTRL+C`) to exit `while True` and should be avoided landing while python still opening a file.

Since the new text need to be appended (not replaced), use `a` in open. Furthermore, use f-string `f""` for better readability

```py
from pysolar.solar import *
import datetime
import time

lat = 47.4569019
long = -122.2095766

PATH = "YOUR_PATH_TO_FILE.txt"
while True:
    with open(PATH, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        date = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
        altitude_deg = get_altitude(lat, long, date)
        t = time.localtime()
        current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)

        f.write(f"LocalTime = {current_time}")
        f.write("\n")
        f.write(f"UTC = {datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)}")
        f.write("\n")
        f.write(f"Elevation = {get_altitude(lat, long, date)}")
        f.write("\n")
        f.write(f"Azimuth = {get_azimuth(lat, long, date)}") 
        f.write("\n")
        f.write(f"Watts per SQmtr = {radiation.get_radiation_direct(date, altitude_deg)}")
        f.write("\n")
        
    time.sleep(60)
```

Result using `sleep(2)`:

```
LocalTime = 22:13:30
UTC = 2022-03-23 15:13:30.454200+00:00
Elevation = 10.740205429854784
Azimuth = 100.02799551004703
Watts per SQmtr = 488.4820597901313
LocalTime = 22:13:32
UTC = 2022-03-23 15:13:32.467925+00:00
Elevation = 10.745759182154947
Azimuth = 100.0343584719799
Watts per SQmtr = 488.7007762103689
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from pysolar.solar import *
import datetime
import time

lat = 47.4569019
long = -122.2095766

while True:
  
  f = open("c:/Users/Jerry/DateWrite.txt", 'a', encoding='utf-8')
  date = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
  altitude_deg = get_altitude(lat, long, date)
  t = time.localtime()
  current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
  
  print("LocalTime=", (current_time))
  print("UTC=", date)
  print("Elevation=", (get_altitude(lat, long, date)))
  print("Azimuth=", (get_azimuth(lat, long, date)))
  print("Watts per SQmtr=", (radiation.get_radiation_direct(date, altitude_deg)))
  UTC = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
  El = get_altitude(lat, long, date)
  Az= get_azimuth(lat, long, date)
  f.write(str(UTC))
  f.write("\n")
  f.write(str(El))
  f.write("\n")
  f.write(str(Az))
  f.write("\n")
  f.close()
  time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Don't use `f = open()`, especially in this manner. This code use infinite loop of `while True:` and require external use of something like `CTRL+C` to stop. It must be avoided to force close python while opening a file. Using `with open()` is safer.